# How to convert String to Date "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" in java

Tags: java, datetime-format

I have a string date. Eg: `"2020-02-21 16:36:30.072"` and I want to convert it to Date `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`. (i.e. `2020-02-21T16:36:30.072+05:30`)

How? Could you please help me?

Comment: `2020-02-21T16:36:30.072+05:30` does not fit the pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"`. Please include your own research and attempt to solve it in the question.

Comment: see the SimpleDateFormatter

Comment: I editted the question

Comment: The [comment by ernest_k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60349673/how-to-convert-string-to-date-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz-in-java#comment106756433_60349673) refers to your formatting pattern using a hard-coded `Z` which means UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds). Yet your example result has an offset of `+05:30`. These are contradictory. You need to pick one or the other.

Comment: Another issue: Never put `Z` in single-quotes. That makes it merely a hard-coded string and will be considered as meaningless. But `Z` has vital meaning as a formatting code. Read the documentation for `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani No, please don’t. The `SimpleDateFormat` class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. We want [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) here.

Comment: Do you want `Z` (that is, UTC), or do you want `+05:30`? Please correct your requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to start by converting the `String` into a more "malleable" format - something which can represent the date/time in a way through which you can generate different formats based on your need

Since it's 2020, you should start with the `java.time.*` API.

```
String input = "2020-02-21 16:36:30.072";
DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(input, inputFormatter);
```

Ok, now, part of your requirement is to have the time zone, so you'll need to convert the `LocalDateTime` to a `ZonedDateTime`, you could, technically, do this in a single step, but it's a good demonstration

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
String output = outputFormatter.format(zdt);

System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(output);
```

This will output

```
2020-02-21 16:36:30.072
2020-02-21T16:36:30.072+11:00
```

I live in Australia, so my time zone is +10 (and +1 for daylight savings).  You can specify a specific time zone if you wish, this is just for demonstration (and I couldn't be bothered trying to figure out 530+ time zone ;))

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

Here is a one-liner.

```
LocalDateTime
.parse(
    "2020-02-21 16:36:30.072".replace( " " , "T" )
)                                                   // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object. *Not* a moment, *not* a point on the timeline. Just a date and a time-of-day, nothing more. Lacks context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.
.atZone(                                            // Lending context to our `LocalDateTime` object to determine a moment by assigning a time zone.
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" )                     // Currently using an offset of five and a half hours ahead of UTC.
)                                                   // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.format(                                            // Generates text representing the value of the `ZonedDateTime` object.
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME          // Pre-defined formatter. No need to specify your own formatting pattern. Your desired format complies with the ISO 8601 standard.
)                                                   // Returns a `String`.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/OVClZh).

> 2020-02-21T16:36:30.072+05:30

## Details

The [Answer by MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60349953/642706) is correct and nicely detailed. I will take some shortcuts, and address specifically your desired offset of +05:30.

We can parse your input as a `LocalDateTime` by merely replacing the SPACE character in the middle with an uppercase `T`.

```
String input = "2020-02-21 16:36:30.072".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

A `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. It lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Your desired offset of `+05:30` is currently used in only two time zones:

- `Asia/Colombo`  (Sri Lanka)
- `Asia/Kolkata`  (India)

Pick which one is yours.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
```

Apply to your `LocalDateTime` to determine a moment, resulting in a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Generate a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format extended wisely to append the name of the zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

If you really want the offset only without the time zone, keep in mind that readers of your data won't know for sure if you meant Sri Lanka time or India time. If you insist, use the predefined `DateTimeFormatter` object as shown in the other Answer.

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

Comment: Awesome comment. Thank you for providing also table.
I could use directly `ZonedDateTime` for my format `2020-02-21T16:36:30Z` without any replaces in String.

Answer (score -4):

import java.util.Date;

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s0="2020-02-21 16:36:30.072";
    Date date=new Date();
    String sd=s0.split(" ")[0];
    date.setDate(Integer.parseInt(sd.split("-")[2]));
    date.setMonth(Integer.parseInt(sd.split("-")[1])-1);
    date.setYear(Integer.parseInt(sd.split("-")[0])-1900);
    String st=s0.split(" ")[1];
    date.setSeconds((int) Double.parseDouble(st.split(":")[2]));
    date.setMinutes(Integer.parseInt(st.split(":")[1]));
    date.setHours(Integer.parseInt(st.split(":")[0]));
    System.out.print(date);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. That’s the hard way. And using the `setDate`, `setMonth` and `setYear` methods that have been deprecated for over 20 years. Certainly far from recommended. Also code-only answers are seldom helpful. It’s from the explanations that we all learn.

Comment: Also the result is not accurate (neither before nor after your edit). I got a `Date` equal to `2020-02-21T15:36:30.909Z`, so 837 milliseconds too far ahead.